# Can't output to file with sed >

Tags: sed, files

I'm messing around with sed for fun and have a little function I found that replaces a few characters:

```
sed 's/"p"$/0/;s/"e"/1/' sedtext.txt
```

Where `sedtext.txt` is as follows:

```
1, 2, 6, 7, "p" 
1, 6, 7, 2, "e"
```

When I do the following I get the desired output:

```
sed 's/"p"$/0/;s/"e"/1/' sedtest.txt > sedtest2.txt
```

But when I try to overwrite the input file with the output I get a blank file:

```
sed 's/"p"$/0/;s/"e"/1/' sedtest.txt > sedtest.txt
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: No, shell redirections are set up before the commands run.

Comment: No. The shell opens (and truncates) the file before even executing the command. `sed` just prints to `stdout`, which the shell pointed at a file. It reads here from the file that the shell already ate

Comment: sed 's/"p"$/0/;s/"e"/1/' sedtest.txt > sedtest2.txt && mv sedtest2.txt sedtest.txt

Comment: You are changing the file while being processed. Use -i for that:

    sed -i 's/"p"$/0/;s/"e"/1/' sedtext.txt

Comment: The `-i` (in-place) switch of GNU `sed` does (almost) exactly your workaround

Comment: Look at specifically this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators#answer-186126